Dynamic Pages with [slug] Not Working on Vercel
I'm using a Next.js app with the app directory structure. I have a dynamic projects page
projects/[slug]/page.tsx.
When I run the project on localhost, it works perfectly. However, when I upload it to Vercel and click a dynamic route, it always results in an error (not found).
I tried to create a static page under the projects folder:
projects/test/page.tsx
This works perfectly.
However, when I visit this link on Vercel  mydomain/projects/[slug]  it shows me the content, but it no longer works on localhost.

you need build your project first

The first time I uploaded my project on Vercel, I didn't have dynamic pages. At that time, the problem was with the error page. When I navigated to
for e.g  /projects/bla, Vercel redirected me to its error page, not mine. So, I added a vercel.json file to my project:
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/error" }]
}

This fixed the error page problem, but when I wanted to use dynamic routes, it always showed my custom error page.
My problem with dynamic pages is fixed now, but my custom error page still isn't working. However, other hosting platforms like Netlify don't have these problems and works perfectly.
